# React Native WebView onMessage doesn`t work

Tags: react-native

My companent

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

class Html extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.webView = null;
    }

    onMessage( event ) {
        console.log( "On Message", event.nativeEvent.data );
    }

    sendPostMessage(msg) {
        console.log( "Sending post message",msg );
        this.webView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }

    runJSInBackground (code) {
      this.webView.injectJavaScript(code)
    }


  render() {  
    return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        ref={( webView ) => this.webView = webView}
        onMessage={this.onMessage}
        onError={(e)=>console.log("WebView error: "+e)}
        source={{
          baseUrl:"include/",
          html: `
          <html>
              <head>
              </head>
            <body>
            <script>
            document.addEventListener("message",function(event) {
                console.log("Received post message", event); //Work!!!
            }, false);

            setTimeout(()=>window.postMessage("WhatsAppMANNN!!!"),5000) //doesn`t work ((
            </script>
            </body>
          </html>
          ` }}
      />
    )
  }

}

export default Html;
```

Everything works fine when I send a WebView request, but there is no answer to the return. That is, the window.postMessage method does not work, and the error does not light either. What's the catch, not how I can not find the answer to this question.

Comment: Try with webView.postMessage("WhatsAppMANNN!!!"),5000)

Comment: Does not help, tried and wait for the bridge function waitForBridge() {
            if (window.postMessage.length !== 1)
              setTimeout(waitForBridge, 200);
            else
              window.postMessage('abcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc');
            }
            window.onload = waitForBridge;

Comment: waiting for the bridge with window.postMessage.length === 1 does not work since chrome 70

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
window.postMessage("Lulz", "*")
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage